# Windows 10 reset password

Tags: windows, windows-10

I intend to either reset a password of a user, or add a new user on my windows 10 machine with lost password.
All the tutorials point to using utilman as cmd. I know it worked a year ago, but now it does not. I succesfully swapped `utilman.exe` to `cmd.exe` but after clicking the utils button the console does not appear. I heard a tip that you have to be in time before windows defender activates in 30 seconds, but even in 6 seconds it did not work.

What can I do now to reset the password to my account?

Comment: I still use this method up to this day, so it should work. In order for us to help you, we need to know where in the steps it fails. What have you done, what happens at each step, and what did you expect to happen? Please edit your post and provide the necessary information. As it is currently written, the post is too vague to help you.

Also, keep in mind, this technique CANNOT be used to alter the password of a Windows Live account. If you indeed login with your windows live account, use another computer to reset the password.

Comment: Added edits as you requested

Comment: Try reboot the computer by pressing the power button and see if it works then.

Comment: Windows Defender does not prevent you from correctly resetting a password, and it also begins running well before you can login to the computer. This 30 seconds thing you mention is either very wrong, or refers to something else entirely.